# Fail2ban not respecting email settings

Tags: email, fail2ban, debian-jessie, ssmtp

In Fail2ban I have set up my email settings as:

```
# Destination email address used solely for the interpolations in
# jail.{conf,local} configuration files.
destemail = me@hotmail.com

#
# Name of the sender for mta actions
sendername = mailer@example.com

# Email address of the sender
sender = mailer@example.com
```

I have set this in my `/etc/fail2ban/jail.local` and `/etc/fail2ban/jail.conf` files, however when I look at my Mailgun domain logs I am seeing that the message is not being delivered due to is not being RFC 5322.

When I am looking in the message headers, which are in the logs on Mailgun, I can see:

```
"message": {
    "headers": {
      "to": "root",
      "message-id": "20160515041935.56055.7228.B699C442@mg.example.com",
      "from": "Fail2Ban <fail2ban>",
      "subject": "[Fail2Ban] recidive: banned 183.3.202.174 from example.com"
    },
```

I have a rule setup to send any emails for root to my email address.

Why is it not sending them to the correct email address intially, and how do I fix this/make the emails RFC 5322 compliant?

**Server info**

- Debian Jessie
- sSMTP as my email client
- Fail2ban version: `Fail2Ban v0.8.13`

Please let me know if you need any more information

Answer (score 0):

Message to : **root**

From : **Fail2ban**

Looks like your SMTP re-writes or aliases aren't working correctly.

I would start by checking there

**Edit**
Without further details it is hard for me to say - but it sounds like you might have a configuration issue with sSMTP

Comment: But it shouldn't even need to worry about my re-writes or aliases as they are defined inside the `jail.local` file and should be used instead of just populating root in there.

Comment: it's sending to root because that is the default destination defined in the action.

Answer (score 0):

Why sSMTP?

Fail2ban support two MTAs.

Add this

```
# E-mail action. Since 0.8.1 Fail2Ban uses sendmail MTA for the
# mailing. Change mta configuration parameter to mail if you want to
# revert to conventional 'mail'.
mta = sendmail
```

here

```
/etc/fail2ban/jail.local
```

Another helpful hint is to make sure your variables name are correct....

I was pulling my hair out until I realized I was using...

```
destmail = my@email.com
```

instead of the correct

```
destemail = my@email.com
```

Look closely and you will see those values get passed to the actions defined in action.d.

For example,

```
**action_mwl = ....., dest="%(destemail)s, ....**
```

So yeah, don't override the dest in the action file.